# How can I select a drop down with div tag in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

HTML CODE:

[image]

My code for this dropdown selection is:

```java
WebElement LocationInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]"));
LocationInput.click();
pauseFor(3);
WebElement CountryName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]"));
Actions actions1 = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(CountryName).sendKeys("Canadian").sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
pauseFor(4);
```

This code is selecting another dropdown, but I want to select the dropdown with link text containing Canadian in it

How can I select this dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

you can adapt your xpath to achieve this.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*/*[contains(@text, 'Canadian')]");
```

contains() can also be used to search for other identifiers, e.g. `@class`

using `//*[text()="Canadian..."]` is also possible but here the text needs to be exaclty the same.

xpath Tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

xpath cheatsheet: https://devhints.io/xpath